# Adding a Linux server to an AD domain where the DC is not directly reachable

Tags: linux, domain, remote

I have a lab environment where we have different environments and we need to register local Linux servers to Domain controllers that are otherwise not visible, or reachable by a broadcast, How can I explicitely declare which domain controller I want my server to register when I use the "net ads join" command to join the domain ?

Comment: How are you expecting to join a domain if you can't reach the servers?  In any case Samba should be using DNS to locate your DCs, not broadcasts.  Using the same resolution method your Windows clients use by looking up the appropriate SRV records.

Comment: AD doesn't rely on broadcasts - all that is required is your DNS to be set up properly so AD clients can query the correct SRV records to find a DC, routes between the DC and client, and the necessary ports allowed through the firewall.

Comment: OK. I verified and the IP of the AD server is reachable, if you know it. My issue is HOW/WHERE do I declare this IP. I use SLES 11.1. My other issue, that I perhaps did not comment well enough is that we work in labs, or pockets where the servers are setup, and each pocket has an adressing space of 192.168.140.0/23 and the IP of the DC is in another pocket so it also has the same IP space, but is also reachable, inter-pocket, on an UP such as 192.168.155.65. This implemented by vSpace from VMware. So the server that I reach has an IP of 192.168.141.210, but is reached by 192.168.155.65.

Answer (score 0):

Either the DC is visible enough to the environment for hosts to join it, or it isn't visible enough for them to.

As long as the linux hosts can resolve the DNS name of the domain and one or more of the DCs (preferably all of them though), from a DNS tree managed by the domain (so it has the SRV records for _msdcs etc.), and can contact the DCs on all the ports required (LDAP and kerberos in particular), it should be fine.

Reaching them by a broadcast would only be required in a legacy scenario (think NT 4).